# No sound in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, sound, lts

I have installed Ubuntu few weeks ago. It is working fine, but it doesn't have sound. I made all upgrades, but this doesn't help. How I can sound work?

PS I can't upgrade to 12.10, my graphic card doesn't support it.

Thanks!

Comment: Same was the problem with me. I upgraded to 14.04. Working fine now.

Comment: I can't upgrade, my computer will work slow...

Answer (score 0):

Install or reinstall soundcard drivers and needed packages :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r` alsa-base alsa-firmware-loaders alsa-oss alsa-source alsa-tools alsa-tools-gui alsa-utils alsamixergui
```

Comment: this doesn't work... :(